# How do I change the layout of an Appixia BasicItemListActivity module?

Tags: mobile, appixia

When using the simple item list module `BasicItemListActivity` you don't have the ability to customize the layout of the item list, you can only change the colors. What should I do when I want a customization like having a list with several images per item or several text fields / prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BasicItemListActivity` is a bit too simple for these requirements. What you're looking for is actually one of the powerful views like `ItemGridView` (for tables or grids) or `ItemCarouselView` (for carousels).

Each of these views actually displays another custom view for each of the items you have. A good view to choose for this purpose is `BasicItemCellView` - which offers a lot of customization on how each item in the list is presented. Don't forget to connect the BasicItemCellView to the container view using the `CellModule` property.